# What is the difference between a shutdown after Windows update and a normal shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

My PC has a weird problem: every time I shutdown, it automatically restarts itself (how to resolve this is not the question). The only time this does not happen is when a Windows update (Windows 10) is applied on shutdown.

What does Windows 10 do different on a post-update-shutdown compared to a normal shutdown?

Comment: after a windows update it will install the updates, that is the only difference.

Comment: Some updates applied during shutdown will cause the completion of updates on startup. But the computer still shuts down normally.  For this reason, I prefer to restart and complete before finally shutting down. But updates are not the cause of your computer failing to shutdown.